# Is there a building tree for Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

Is there a building tree for Die2Nite, if so where can I find it?

Answer (score 18):

**8/10/2011 Update:** This is based on version 1 of the game.  Much has changed in version 2, so don't take this as gospel unless someone updates it.

**Key to the "Awesome" column:**

```
♦     Not useful         U - Can be upgraded -- see below.
♦♦    Meh                ! - Only lasts one night! Waste of resources.
♦♦♦   Nice to have       
♦♦♦♦  Get it if you can  N - number of nuts and bolts required
♦♦♦♦♦ MUST HAVE ASAP     D - number of defensive objects required
N/A   Purely defensive upgrade - awesomeness depends on your choices
                                 and what you have in the bank.
```

### Workshop

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Workshop          Convert scrap to building material for 3 AP  - 1 ♦♦♦♦♦ U  25
└┬ Diary          Improve construction logs                    - 1 ♦        15
 ├ Butcher        Convert pets in food                         - - ♦♦       40
 │ └─ Cremato-cue Convert corpses in 4× human flesh            - - ♦        45
 ├ Def. Focus     Increase defensive value of defensive items  6 - ♦♦♦♦♦ U  50
 ├ Factory        -1 to workshop costs                         3 - ♦♦♦♦♦    40
 ├ Screaming saws +40 defense                                  - - N/A      65
 ├ Gallows        Hang next citizen receiving 8 complaints     - - ♦        65
 └ Cannon mounds  +10 defense                                  - 1 ♦♦       50
   └┬ Plate gun   +50 defense                                  5 3 N/A      35
    ├ Perforator  +45 defense                                  4 - N/A      30
    ├ Stone can.  +60 defense                                  - 3 N/A      45
    └ Breaker     +12 defense                                  - - N/A      15
```

### Portal Lock

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Portal lock       Stop gate from reopening 20' before attack   - - ♦♦       16
└┬ Piston lock    Automatically close gate 30' before attack   4 - ♦        25
 └ Armour plating +12 defense                                  - - N/A      35
```

### Foundations

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Foundations       Nothing, but unlocks epic projects           - 2 ♦        30
└┬ False town     +210 defense                                10 - N/A     600
 ├ Mega pump      +150 water in well                           - 3 ♦♦♦♦    170
 ├ Big rebuild    +180 defense                                 - 5 N/A     800
 └ Plumbing       Refill water weapons (and def?) for free     4 - ♦♦♦♦♦   130
```

### Pump

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Pump              +10 water, can extract 2 ration/day/person   - - ♦♦♦♦♦ U  25
└┬ Water turrets  +60 defense, but needs water in well (?)     - - N/A   U  60
 ├ Water purifier +8 water per jerry can                       - - ♦♦♦♦♦    50
 │ └┬ Veg. plot   +3 regular food/day; +3 7 AP food/day (ca)   - - ♦♦♦♦♦    60
 │  └ Watermine.  +75 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  25
 ├ Hydraulic net. +15 water in well                            5 - ♦♦♦♦     40
 │ └┬ Sprinklers  +95 defense                                  - - N/A      50
 │  ├ Macerator   +45 defense                                  - 2 N/A      55
 │  └ Washer      +50 defense                                  1 - N/A      50
 └ Drilling rig   +40 water in well                            - - ♦♦♦♦♦    60
   └─ Eden proj.  +70 water in well                            - - ♦♦♦♦♦    65
```

### Watchtower

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Watchtower        Estimate tonight's attack, +3 defense        - - ♦♦♦♦♦ U  12
└┬ Enh. map       Get zombie counts per tile                   - - ♦♦♦♦♦    15
 ├ Catapult       Fire objects in the desert for 4AP           - - ♦        40
 │ └─ Enh. cat.   -2 to catapult cost                          - - ♦        30
 ├ Search tower   Detects, improves desert regeneration        - - ♦♦♦♦♦ U  30
 ├ Scanner        -50% to people required for best estimation  1 - ♦        20
 │ └─ Predictor   Predict tomorrow's attack from tower         - - ♦♦♦      20
 └ Emergency sup. +5 defense, unlocks emergency projects       - - ♦♦       40
   └┬ Explodage   +35 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  18
    ├ Rub. heap   +10 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  10
    │ └─ Mt. Kill +50 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  35
    ├ Guerilla    +45 defense for 1 night                      2 - N/A   !  21
    ├ Baited trap +45 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  18
    ├ Em. defense +40 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  26
    └ Spike trap  +25 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  11
```

### Great Wall Strengthening

```
Tech              Use                                          N D Awesome  AP
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Gr. Wall Stength. +7 defense                                   - - ♦♦♦♦♦    30
└┬ Barbs          +9 defense                                   - - N/A      20
 │ └─ Lure        +10 defense for 1 night                      - - N/A   !  10
 ├ Barricades     +25 defense                                  5 - N/A      50
 ├ Great pit      +20 defense                                  - - N/A   U  80
 │ └┬ Spiked pit  +50 defense                                  - - N/A      60
 │  └ Moat        +45 defense                                  - - N/A      50
 ├ Zombie grater  +75 defense                                  5 3 N/A      60
 ├ Old sch. traps +30 defense                                  - - N/A      65
 ├ Razor wall     +40 defense                                  5 - N/A      40
 └ Ramparts       +5 defense                                   6 - ♦♦♦♦♦    40
   └┬ Über Wall   +70 defense                                  - 2 N/A      50
    ├ Beams       +25 defense                                  2 - N/A      55
    ├ Interior W. +70 defense                                  - - N/A      65
    ├ Upgrade. W. +15 defense                                  0 1 N/A   U  65
    └ Spiked W.   +50 defense                                  4 - N/A      35
```

### Projects of the day

Keep in mind all of the projects of the day start from "level" 0.

```
Project          Improves                   Level 0    1    2    3    4    5
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Workshop         Construction costs             100%  93%  86%  79%  72%  65%
Watch tower      Detection range                  ?    3km  6km 10km 10km 10km
                 Enter town if closer than*       0    0    0    0    1km  2km
Search tower     Regeneration chance per tile     ?   37%  49%  61%  73%  85%
Great pit        Defense                         20d  33d  54d  86d 119d 170d
Upgradeable wall Defense                         15d  51d  86d 123d 182d 243d
Pump             Water in well (one time)       +10w +20w +20w +30w +30w   ?
Defensive focus  Defense value of def. item     2.5d 3.2d 4.4d 5.8d 6.6d 8.0d
Water turrets    Defense                         60d 108d 156d 204d 252d 300d
                 Water/day consumed               0    2w   4w   6w   9w  12w

*If you are closer than this range from the town, you may enter the town gates
```

**Awesomeness:**

- Workshop upgrades only really help with the epic projects. The gains for the rest are negligible.
- Watch tower upgrades up to level 3 are practically required for worry-free expeditions. The rest is nice to have.
- Search tower upgrades are important to always have nearby undepleted areas.
- Great pit upgrades are pretty meh. Upgrade the upgradeable wall instead, if you can.
- Upgradeable pit upgrades are nice, but finite. Even 51 defense is nothing to sneeze at, but they only help you so much.
- Defensive focus upgrades are pretty much a must-have. When everything is built and everything is upgraded, only defensive focus keeps improving your defense with every single defensive item. They outscore upgradeable wall after the 42nd defensive item circa.
- Pump upgrades are nice to have but hardly earth-breaking.
- Water turret upgrades seem to do more harm than good...

The French do not agree with my assessments and see getting a level 5 workshop as a requirement for a successful city.

Comment: For your consideration: all buildings, fully upgraded, give a total of __1783 defense__ (__2118 defense__ including all the temporary projects.) According to PataPata, the average attack for __day 17__ is 1738. Defensive focus is _that_ important :)

Comment: I agree that defensive focus is important eventually, but no town I've ever been in had anywhere near the number of defensive items your current town does.  Even our town at day 14 got more defense from pit upgrades than building defensive focus.  So I think your impression of it might be skewed by the success of your current town's scavenging.  I think it is important later game, but not so much early.

Comment: @bwarner It's quite possible that what you mean is true -- we _do_ have a ton of scavengers in our city (9?), while during beta heroes were few and far between. Still, everything else can only bring you so far.

Comment: ASCII win. However I recommend changing the "Awesomeness rating" to use a symbol which doesn't merge with itself - it's difficult to tell in a glance whether something has 4 or 5 awesomeness at the moment.

Comment: @Oak Originally I used `◆`, but they were too wide. Maybe `♦` otoh...

Comment: workshop level 1 upgrade is 93%. (100-7). seem like a small type but.

Comment: Under Watch Tower, what does the desert travel and AP relate to? It typically costs me 1AP to move from one square to another. Does this effect that?

Comment: @FOak Clarified -- you get to reenter the town gates for free from 1km (2km) away, thus saving you 1 AP (2 AP) on all of your desert travel.

Comment: Small correction: Watch tower is upgradeable and I am quite sure enhanced map is not.

Comment: Watchtower upgrades are a bit off.  At level 4 it allows you free returns from within 1km, which generally translates to 2 AP.  At level 5 it allows free returns from within 2km, which generally translates to 3 AP.

Comment: @bwarner Sigh, is this any clearer? That column is too narrow to explain the concept :(

Comment: @Badp I like that you had it as AP before, I would just change it to 2AP and 3AP.  If someone wants to understand why those values are correct, they can ask a separate question.

Comment: Only thing that's misleading about defensive focus is the statement "They outscore upgradeable wall after the 42nd defensive item circa."

After the 30th item defensive focus outpaces upgradable wall except for the first upgrade.  You get 35/upgrade on the wall, and you get 36/upgrade on defensive focus with 30 items.

Answer (score 3):

[This Die2Nite wiki](http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Buildings) has a list of everything that can be built, what it costs, and what it does.

And [this other wiki](http://die2nitewiki.com/wiki/Buildings) has a list of the building tree along with the AP costs at each level of workshop upgrades.  Which might be a useful tool to convince people not to do workshop upgrades...